# How To Sign a Jar File for an Applet?

Tags: java, jar, japplet, appdata, signed-applet

Does Singing a Jar File For an Applet use the same process as signing a Jar file for an application?? If so, can someone tell me how to sign it? I have an Applet that writes to your APPDATA, kinda like Minecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the same process. Search for "sign jar" and you will find many tutorials.

[Here is a nice one](http://web.archive.org/web/20120511014111/http://cokeandcode.com/index.html?page=tutorials/webstart)

Comment: Link goes to a game building website.

Comment: i have replaced the link with one from webarchive.